# getting Serror { Commwake devExch } error at boot time

Tags: 16.10, disk

[click here to see the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTFp8.jpg)

i am using ubuntu gnome 16.10 on a laptop and on boot it shows a series of

```
    ata6: Serror { CommWake DevExch  }

    ata6: irq_stat 0x00000040 connection status changed
```

how can i correct that?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306104/exception-emask-0x10-sact-0x0-serr-0x4060000-action-0xe-frozen-t2

Do you have any external devices plugged in at boot?